# how to get particular data from jsonarray?

Tags: android

I want to get the CreateDate value from xml file
the xml file is like this way.

```
<d:CreateDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2012-03-18T15:11:30.403</d:CreateDate>
```

I created JSONObject as

```
JSONObject json=new WCFServices().getWhatsNew();//i get the json object WCFServices class.
JSONArray whatsnew= json.getJSONArray("d");
String CreateDate= c.getString("CreateDate");
```

if i try to print the value it gives me output  as:

```
 /Date(1330041600000)/
```

I want to get the value as like `2012-03-18T15:11:30.403`
how to get it ?

Comment: Make more clear so we can answer it

Comment: how can you parse a xml file using JsonArray?

Comment: cast xml to json first. then get the JsonArray. After getting array, then get the JsonObject from that array by placing `Date`

Comment: just want to make sure that output of 2012-03-18T15:11:30.403 is (1330041600000)? or you just post example value?

Comment: So, you're not getting the right output as `/Date(1300....)/`. First you need to get the exact value, then I think you need to use SimpleDateFormat class and then pass your timestamp to it it will make it to datetime.

Comment: @Hamza Waqas, If you assuming that output is epoch date then conversion of that value is 24/02/2012 05:30:00.

Comment: So, `133401..` is your timestamp I think. right?

Comment: @venkat I'm just checking that your output is in epoch or not. Because conversion of that epoch to normal is 24/02/2012 05:30:00. But you said your datetime is 2012-03-18T15:11:30.

Comment: @HamzaWaqas thank you i understand i need to convert the epoch date to ordinary date is it ok  thank you very much

Comment: To change it to your appropriate format, go through SimpleFormat class. Pass the placeholders for the Date as you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your output is in epoch date format. So you need to convert it to normal date time. Try this for it..

```
public String normal_date_time(String epoch_date)
    {
      try
      {
         long epoch = Long.parseLong( epoch_date );

         String dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS";
         SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);     
         Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
         calendar.setTimeInMillis(epoch);
         String formated_date =  formatter.format(calendar.getTime()); 
         Log.d("Date", formated_date);
         return formated_date;
      }
      catch (Exception e) 
      {
        // TODO: handle exception
          return null;
      }
```

You can find more about DateFormat by following links, It will help you to retrieve output in different formats.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html

Hope this will help you..And don't forget to accept this if it help you.

Thanks...